# Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script

Tags: php, laravel

I just started to develop web application with Laravel, I have a problem to use the dependency injection. It works fine without the DI, but I want to refactor the code so that the code is not tightly coupled.

I already search in google that suggests perhaps there is a white space before the namespace and search related questions here, but none of them solve my problem.

**AccountController**

```
<?php

namespace TabJut\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

use View;

use TabJut\Http\Requests;
use TabJut\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use TabJut\Repositories\AccountRepository;

class AccountController extends Controller
{
    /* error culprit, If I remove these the page not error */
    protected $repository;

    public function __construct(AccountRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }
    /* error culprit */

    public function getLogin()
    {
        return View::make('account.login');
    }

    public function postLogin()
    {
        // Validates inputs.
        $rules = array(
            'username' => 'required', 
            'password' => 'required'
        );
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        // Redirects back to the form if the validator fails.
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::action('AccountController@getLogin')
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
        } 

        $username = Input::get('username');
        $password = Input::get('password');
        $user = $repository.Authenticate($username, $password);
        var_dump($user);
    }
}
```

**AccountRepository**

```
<?php

namespace TabJut\Repositories;

use DB;

class AccountRepository
{
    public function Authenticate($username, $password)
    {
        $user = DB::table('users')
                    ->where('is_active', '1')
                    ->where('user_name', $username)
                    ->where('password', $password)
                    ->first();    
        return $user;
    }
}
```

**Folder Tree**

[image: Folder Tree]

**Error Message**

> FatalErrorException in AccountRepository.php line 3: Namespace
>   declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script
>
> ```
> in AccountRepository.php line 3
> at FatalErrorException->__construct() in HandleExceptions.php line 127
> at HandleExceptions->fatalExceptionFromError() in HandleExceptions.php line 112
> at HandleExceptions->handleShutdown() in HandleExceptions.php line 0
> at Composer\Autoload\includeFile() in ClassLoader.php line 301
> ```

Did I miss any important configuration like service locator setup or just unseen code error?

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has nothing to do with the dependency injection, based on kuzawinski comment on the manual, I recreated the file with notepad and it solves the problem.

> ...and you still get "Namespace declaration statement has to be the
>   very first statement in the script" Fatal error, then you probably use
>   UTF-8 encoding (which is good) with Byte Order Mark, aka BOM (which is
>   bad). Try to convert your files to "UTF-8 without BOM", and it should
>   be ok. [Comment](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php#115504)